# Upload blobs with metadata, node

Tags: node.js, azure

How would I go about uploading blob metadata into Azure in Node? I have:

```
blobService.createBlockBlobFromText(containerName, function(error) { 
    //what would go in here? 
});
```

I see that there is a [link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/dd179414.aspx) to set blob metadata, but I can't really interpret what it means.

Does anyone know if it's possible to set blob metadata in Node?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this code. This creates a blob in a blob container using [`createBlockBlobFromText`](https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-node/blob/bcfd581a0e1d5adfae24cb94d7aa006fc2edaed9/lib/services/legacyStorage/lib/blob/blobservice.js) method and sets two metadata items with the blob:

```
var AZURE = require('azure');
TestBlobUpload('testcontainer');
function TestBlobUpload(ContainerName)
{
    var blobService = AZURE.createBlobService('UseDevelopmentStorage=true'); // error occurred at this line 
    blobService.createContainerIfNotExists(ContainerName, {publicAccessLevel : 'blob'}, function(error){
        if(!error)
        {
            console.log("Container created successfully.");
            blobService.createBlockBlobFromText(ContainerName, 'simplefile.txt', 'Sample content', {
                metadata: {
                    'a': 'a',
                    'b': 'b',
                }}, function(error){
                if(!error) {
                    console.log("Blob created from Text successfully.");
                } else {
                    console.log("error: "+error);
                }
            });
        }
        else
        {
            console.log("error: "+error);

        }
    });
}
```

Comment: That's awesome, Gaurav, thank you! Does the first 'a' for 'a': 'a' refer to a new object in the metadata called 'a'? How would I reference it?

Comment: The first "a" is the metadata key and the second "a" is the value. Should've used different values :). Not sure what you mean by "How would I reference it". Would you please explain.

Comment: Excellent, thanks, Gaurav, that actually makes sense and it seems pretty straightforward to retrieve the metadata from the key. Thanks for your help!!